# .bat script that moves file to a folder and adds date

Tags: scripting

I've pieced together this script to try and move a file from a folder to another, and add a date to the end of the file.  It worked once, but hasn't worked since.  This is my first script, and I was hoping an expert would take a look and advise if they see something wrong here.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off

move "c:\ic\test source\*.*" "c:\test destination"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%_%HH%%Min%%Sec%
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script I wrote to do what you were looking for.

```
$SourcePath = "c:\test\*.txt"
$DestPath = "c:\test2\"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -path $SourcePath

foreach ($File in $files)
    {
      $DateTime =   get-date -format "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
      $NewName = $DestPath + $file.basename + " " + $DateTime +  $file.Extension
      Move-Item -path $file.FullName -Destination $NewName -Verbose
    }
```